# Angular-ui bootstrap: Date CAN NOT be copied inside Tab?

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've a simple Tab which is using Angular-ui bootstrap.

**Inside** the tab, there is a 'date input' <`input type="date"`/>

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Tab A"> 
        Date Input Inside Tab</br>
        Date 1:<input type="date" ng-model="dt1" style="width:150px"/> {{dt1}}
        <p>Copy Date 1: {{copydt1}}</p>
    </tab>
</tabset>  
<button ng-click="copyDate()">click to show Copy Date</button>
```

app.js:

```
$scope.copyDate = function() {
    $scope.copydt1 = $scope.dt1;
    $scope.copydt2 = $scope.dt2;
}
```

The problem is I can not copy the date (**$scope.dt1**) successfully! The date CANNOT be copied?!

However, if I put the 'date input' **Outside** the tab, I've no problem at all!

```
Date Input Outside Tab</br>
Date 2:<input type="date" ng-model="dt2" style="width:150px"/> {{dt2}}
<p>Copy Date 2: {{copydt2}}</p>
```

I've a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RL6SGJNvsCGCiNOrrzVe) to demonstrate the problem.

Please help if I miss anything, and give me a workaround pls.
Or, anyone thinks it's a bug? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing tabset is creating a subscope; similar to what happens if you use an ngInclude.  Neither copydt1, or dt1, will be inherited by this subscope, as they are simple variables on the parent scope.  One work around is to wrap them in an object.

The controller code changes:

```
$scope.dt1Wrapper = {
  dt1 : $filter("date")(aday, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
};

$scope.copydt1Wrapper.copydt1 = $scope.dt1Wrapper.dt1;
```

The html code changes:

```
Date 1:<input type="date" ng-model="dt1Wrapper.dt1" style="width:150px"/> {{dt1Wrapper.dt1}}
<p>Copy Date 1: {{copydt1Wrapper.copydt1}}</p>
```

Once wrapped in an object; they will be inherited by the subscope.

http://plnkr.co/edit/d6lwJTucTZ2SZP1tAcpa?p=preview

Comment: Reboog, thank you for your quick response and your helpful workaround. It works perfect for me!